# Reference referenced resources in loop in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-bicep, azure-rm

I have existing ServiceBus topics and i want to reference their subscriptions in terraform. The question is how to do it when i have multiple topics and i wnat to build reference to subscription in each topic?

```
data "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "subscribe_topics" {
  for_each     = local.subscribe_topics

  name         = each.value
  namespace_id = data.azurerm_servicebus_namespace.sb.id
}

data "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "subscriptions" {
  topic_id = // how to iterate over topic ids from data block above?
  name     = local.sb_subscription_name
}

locals {
  subscribe_topics = [
    "topic1",
    "topic2",
    "topic3"
  ]

  sb_subscription_name = "xyz"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice is your `subscribe_topics` is not suitable for a loop, if you try it like that it will give you an error:

> Error: Invalid for_each argument
>
> The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.

the fix is easy `for_each = toset(local.subscribe_topics)`

---

I don't have those resources to confirm, but all you need is to loop over the topic:

```
data "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "subscribe_topics" {
  for_each     = toset(local.subscribe_topics)

  name         = each.value
  namespace_id = data.azurerm_servicebus_namespace.sb.id
}

data "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "subscriptions" {
  for_each = data.azurerm_servicebus_topic.subscribe_topics

  topic_id = each.value.id
  name     = local.sb_subscription_name
}

locals {
  subscribe_topics = [
    "topic1",
    "topic2",
    "topic3"
  ]

  sb_subscription_name = "xyz"
}
```

---

and another way

```
data "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "subscribe_topics" {
  for_each     = toset(local.subscribe_topics)

  name         = each.value
  namespace_id = data.azurerm_servicebus_namespace.sb.id
}

data "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "subscriptions" {
  for_each = toset(local.subscribe_topics)

  topic_id = data.azurerm_servicebus_topic.subscribe_topics[each.key].id
  name     = local.sb_subscription_name
}

locals {
  subscribe_topics = [
    "topic1",
    "topic2",
    "topic3"
  ]

  sb_subscription_name = "xyz"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I have multiple topics and I want to build reference to subscription in each topic, how to achieve it:

I do agree with **@Helder Sepulveda** and adding `output` block for clear vision of the service bus topics and understanding the configuration. The deployment was successful with the below terraform code as shown.

```bash
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

locals {
  subscribe_topics = [
    "topic1",
    "topic2",
    "topic3"
  ]

  sb_subscription_name = "subsj"
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
    name = "xxxx"
}

data "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "example" {
    name = "newsbxyz"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

data "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "subscribe_topics" {
  for_each     = toset(local.subscribe_topics)

  name         = each.value
  namespace_id = data.azurerm_servicebus_namespace.example.id
  depends_on = [ data.azurerm_servicebus_namespace.example ]
}

data "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "subscriptions" {
  for_each = data.azurerm_servicebus_topic.subscribe_topics

  topic_id = data.azurerm_servicebus_topic.subscribe_topics[each.key].id
  name     = local.sb_subscription_name
  depends_on = [ data.azurerm_servicebus_topic.subscribe_topics ]
}

output "subscriptions_output" {
  value = data.azurerm_servicebus_subscription.subscriptions
}
```

***Deployment successful:***

[image]

Comment: Are those `depends_on` really needed there?

Comment: Yes, it will be efficient if we add `depends_on` block as service bus topics are under namespace and subscriptions are under topics. @HelderSepulveda

Comment: And also it tells the terraform to follow a specific order while deploying the main code. @HelderSepulveda

Comment: @Jahnavi I disagree `depends_on` is needed. That's why there are implicit references, i.e, `namespace_id = data.azurerm_servicebus_namespace.example.id` already tells terraform to wait for the service bus namespace to be created.

Comment: Yep... the `depends_on` should be a last resort, there is no efficiency gained, just an extra line in the code ... just like @MarkoE mentioned there are implicit references